# Can a WebRTC TURN server be hosted within a home network?

Tags: webrtc, nat, stun, turn

I've noticed an issue with my attempt to host a turn server within my home network with port forwarding. When both clients connect from outside the network, the relay works as expected. When one of the clients is within the network, the source IP in the stun/turn packet is an internal network IP and the client seems to ignore it. Has anyone encountered this issue?

If I specify the internal IP for the ICE candidate, it all works, but this isn't a great solution for a client that can exist inside and outside the network.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with running a relay server from within your network, as long as your relay server has a publicly facing port (or 1:1 NAT port translation or equivalent) so that the default relay port 3478 is exposed to the public Internet.

If I understand you correctly, when clients outside your network connect and work as expected, you are mean that both use a candidate pair where a local candidate is a relay candidate. But what about the remote candidate? Is it relay too? This is a little strange, because typically just one relay candidate is needed. Can you clarify? An example with concrete IP addresses could be useful (you should probably alter them for privacy reasons).

Now let's consider a client connecting from within the network. You are saying that a local host candidate (not a relay candidate) is being used. Depending of what you are connecting too, this may be expected: if you are connecting to another client on the same local network, then a relay candidate is not needed as direct local host - local host connectivity should be possible. If, however, you re connecting to a client outside the network and you can be reached via public internet, you may be able to be reached via peer reflexion. Again, a concrete example with some IP addresses and ports could be useful (again, just fake them to preserve privacy).

Also, keep in mind that when two clients connect, they use candidate pairs (a pair of a local and a remote candidates), so please show both.